# EntityFramework populating uniqueidentifier with value "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

Tags: entity-framework, uniqueidentifier

In my WCF service I am using Entity Framework .NET 4.0,
in my database i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tracking](
    [TrackingID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,   
    ...
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tracking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TrackingID] ASC
)
) ON [DATA]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tracking] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Tracking_TrackingID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [TrackingID]
GO
```

when i insert a record Entity framewrok has prepopulated the TrackingID as  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". I have setting field property to be Computed and Identity bu no such luck any ideas: here is my code snippet:

```
using (var context = new DB.PTLEntities())
{
     var tracking = new DB.Tracking();       
     context.Trackings.AddObject(tracking);
     context.SaveChanges();
     trackingID = tracking.TrackingID;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like EF doesnt think this column is an identity column so its putting in default(Guid). Take a look here for some details on making a guid an identity column (it actually goes through your exact example) http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/

Comment: @oxfn try the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20120215161924/http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4 its a shame his blog is offline, i might pull some of this into my answer at some stage

Comment: I see now, that this is not EF problem, but of Visual Studio EDMX generator. It does not set `StoreGeneratedPttern="Identity"` attribute for `uniqueidentifier` columns, even if they have `DEFAULT NEWID()`, so you have to set it manually

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue. Following solution worked for me.

There is a need to change the `StoreGeneratedPattern` value for the property in the EF designer. Set it to `Identity`. This will cause EF to avoid setting the value on an insert, then capture it after the insert is complete.

If your EF version is 4, then you may have trouble with this using the designer only. You may have to edit the `.edmx` manually and set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` in the storage model itself.

Example:

```
< Property Name="EmpId" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (EF >= 4.1) I needed to add a default to the table itself:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
```

Also if you're using your own context, you should tell EF that the column is the identity column:

```
public class ShedContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DraftFromWebOneOff>()
            .Property(d => d.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is about EF >= 4.1